# Powershell: search for multiple string multiple xml and output results to csv

Tags: xml, string, powershell

I need help to search for multiple xml files for multiple string's and then output the results into a csv or txt file. The xml files are all in the same format.

At the moment I can only extract single string from single xml using the following:

```
$xml = [xml](Get-Content 'C:\App\test.xml')
$xml.application.stage1.c_firstname
```

Which returns the name, I need to be able to return `c_surname` and `c_userid` and output that to a csv file(ideally or text) on multiple xml

Sample XML file:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8" ?>
<application>
  <stage1>
    <c_product_name>Test</c_product_name>
    <c_firstname>Bill</c_firstname>
    <c_surname>Gates</c_surname>
  </stage1>
  <stage5>
    <c_number>12345TEST</c_number>
  </stage5>
</application>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I'd load the XML files in a loop and use XPath expressions to extract the text from the nodes in question. Somthing like this:

```
Get-ChildItem "C:\path\to\*.xml" `
  | % { Get-Content $_ | Out-String } `
  | select @{n="c_firstname";e={$_ | Select-Xml "//c_firstname/text()"}},
           @{n="c_userid";e={$_ | Select-Xml "//c_userid"}} `
  | Export-Csv "C:\output.csv" -NoTypeInformation
```

Answer (score 0):

I'm not sure I'm getting your question right but:
If you have an XML input such as:

```
<persons>
<person>
<firstname>Mickey</firstname>
<lastname>Mouse</lastname>
</person>
<person>
<firstname>Donald</firstname>
<lastname>Duck</lastname>
</person>
</persons>
```

Save on d:\temp\Input.xml

Then the command

```
$xml = [xml](get-Content d:\temp\input.xml)
$csv = $xml.persons.person | Convertto-CSV -NoTypeInformation
```

Should do the trick.

Comment: Hi Alex - Sorry i don't think i made the question clear. The xml files looks as below:  <?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8" ?> 
- <application>
- <stage1> 
  <c_name>Test</c_product_name>   
  <c_firstname>Bill</c_firstname> 
  <c_surname>Gates</c_surname> 
</stage1>
<stage5>
  <c__number>12345TEST</c_number> 
</stage5>
I need to extract the firstname, surname and c_number from multiple xml's to csv to txt, does that make sense. Thanks

Comment: @SayfulAhmed Please avoid posting code in comments, because it tends to be almost unreadable. Instead update your question with it (I've taken the liberty to do it for you this time).